# Write to a excel file in asp .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

i have some class based on this class i need to write each class fields as header to excel file in asp .net core.. How can i do this?  I have added my fields to a json string

```
 public string GetVehicles()
        {
            string jsonResult = "[{Feature: '', RegistrationNumber: '', OwnerName: '', MobileNumber: '',Make: '',Model:''," +
                "RegistrationDate: '',MakeYear: '',ModelYear: '',UsageType: '',EngineNumber: '',VehicleType: '', Color: ''}]";
            return jsonResult;
        }
```

Comment: Do you just need to export the class field as a header to Excel, or do you want to export all the data and fields of the class to Excel? Please elaborate.

Comment: @YongqingYu only want to exporta ll the fields of class to excel not the data

Comment: @YongqingYu How to download this generated excel in client side?

Comment: I have update my post , you can refer to it.

Comment: @YongqingYu i am working on angular 8..

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to export fields name to header, you don't need to convert it to json.

Just use `GetType().GetProperties()` to get all fields and bind to each cell.

Please refer to this code:

```
 public IActionResult ExportExcel()
        {
            var myField = new YourClassName().GetType().GetProperties();
            using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Excel1");
                var currentRow = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < myField.Length; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, i + 1).Value = myField[i].Name;

                }
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                    var content = stream.ToArray();
                    return File(
                        content,
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                        "users.xlsx");
                }
            }
        }
```

---

### Update

If you want to export excel in client, you can use **`table2excel`** plugin.

Here is the code:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<string> fields= new MyTableTest().GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(); 
            return View(fields);
        }
```

View:

```
@model List<string>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section Scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Export() {
            $("#tbl").table2excel({
                filename: "Table.xls"
            });
        }
    </script>
}

<table id="tbl" hidden>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <th>
                @item
            </th>
        }
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="ExportExcel" onclick="Export()" />
```

Comment: @AlvinaJose, With the same concept, you can create a table, only display the data of the header, and then complete the corresponding operations in angular8, please refer to: https://medium.com/@patade888/exporting-data-to-excel-in-angular-8-5a7cf5d0d25d